# AWS S3 and Reactjs route

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, routes

I have uploaded my reactjs app in S3, everything is working fine, the routes work well but only on first level subpages.

For example:

```
myapp.com/products -> works
myapp.com/products/1 -> does not work
myapp.com/activate -> works
myapp.com/activate/user -> does not work
```

How can I fix this?

I've already set up the S3 bucket to redirect on index.html also in case of error, but, as I say on top, this work only for first level folder.

On localhost everything works fine.

Comment: Can you include your reactjs code?

Comment: Thank you Mark but as I say in the update the problem is solved by setting homepage in package.json

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but when I write my question I've made some test and I've noticed that react is loading also in deeper level url (app.com/first/second) but the js are not loaded correctly because the path change. The problem is solved by changing the homepage paremeters in package.json from "." to "http://myapp.com"

Hope this help someone.

Thank you